# FileZilla Server.xml is not reloading and showiing changes

Tags: filezilla

I created something basic that will soon allow automatic user uploads for fileZilla, I have not yet made it general, Though what i am curious about is, Why is it that when I look back in the user table of the fileZilla GUI the new user is not being added? All i did was put the xml structure in a write function in php and changed the user from the one I made in the fileZilla GUI.

///write to xml file

```
  $xml ='FileZilla Server/FileZilla Server.xml';


  $handler = fopen($xml,'w');

  fwrite($handler,'<FileZillaServer>
      <Settings>
          <Item name="Admin port" type="numeric">14147</Item>
      </Settings>
      <Groups />
      <Users>
          <User Name="ddf">
              <Option Name="Pass">B7B5349BC807B2C385478AA02C2ADDCEA37F3330994D15457C8CB5ED378EF9C7D0E64D5366048AEFEF8F2424662B25A1025D863ACB5F39093BA04091BE510412</Option>
              <Option Name="Salt">)W5@&apos;jgXQ5^&amp;p2F$Wa2V2F4~RG^Ox9.J24H(:LB)i;M[BbQ8&lt;m,J52@Jt$!8Ms/.</Option>
           <Option Name="Group"></Option>
              <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">0</Option>
              <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
              <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
              <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
              <Option Name="Comments"></Option>
              <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
              <IpFilter>
                  <Disallowed />
                  <Allowed />
              </IpFilter>
              <Permissions>
                  <Permission Dir="C:\Users\greatness\Desktop\New folder">
                      <Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>
                      <Option Name="FileWrite">0</Option>
                      <Option Name="FileDelete">0</Option>
                      <Option Name="FileAppend">0</Option>
                      <Option Name="DirCreate">0</Option>
                      <Option Name="DirDelete">0</Option>
                      <Option Name="DirList">1</Option>
                      <Option Name="DirSubdirs">1</Option>
                      <Option Name="IsHome">1</Option>
                      <Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
                  </Permission>
              </Permissions>
              <SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="0" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="0">
                  <Download />
                  <Upload />
              </SpeedLimits>
          </User>
      </Users>
  </FileZillaServer>
');

}
```

////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, FileZilla Server does not reload the configuration when you change the file.

The FileZilla Server interface uses Admin interface port of FileZilla Server to notify it about a change to make it reload the configuration.

You might be able to implement the same. See [`AdminSocket` class](https://svn.filezilla-project.org/filezilla/FileZilla%20Server/trunk/source/AdminSocket.cpp?view=markup) in FileZilla Server repository.